# Sign up form fails to validate

Tags: php

I wrote this code for a registration form validation but it is not working. It just stores the data in the database with out validating it. It is a sign up form just for practicing some php and I'm also wondering if this script secure enough to be used.

```
<?php
include_once('connection.php');
session_start();

$count_username = "";
$count_email = "";
$count_password = "";
$count_phone = "";
$err_message = array();

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // checking post variables and escaping weird characthers
    $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['firstname']);
    $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['lastname']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['email']);
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['username']);
    $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['phone']);
    $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['city']);
    $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['address']);
    $bank = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['bank']);
    $account = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['account']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['password']);
    $confirmPass = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['confirmpassword']); 

    //form validation

    //validating firstname input
    if(!empty($firstname)){
        $firstname_chk = strip_tags(trim($firstname));
        if(strlen($firstname_chk) > 25){
            array_push($err_message , 'The maximum length you can use is 25');
        }elseif(preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/',$firstname_chk) && preg_match('/[0-9]/',$firstname_chk)){
            array_push($err_message , 'Only letter are allowed');
        }else{
            $_firstname = $firstname_chk;
        }
    }else{
            array_push($err_message , 'First Name can not be empty');
    }
    //validating lastname input
    if(!empty($lastname)){
        $lastname_chk = strip_tags(trim($lastname));
        if(strlen($lastname_chk) > 25){
            array_push($err_message , 'The maximum length you can use is 25');
        }elseif(preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/',$lastname_chk) && preg_match('/[0-9]/',$lastname_chk)){
            array_push($err_message , 'Only letter are allowed');
        }else{
            $_lastname = $firstname_chk;                
        }
    }else{
        array_push($err_message , 'Last Name can not be empty');
    }
    //validating email input
    if(!empty($email)){
        if(preg_match( '/^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/',$email)){
            $email_query = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM Byers WHERE Email = '$email' ");
            $count_email = mysqli_num_rows($email_query);
            if($count_email > 0){
                array_push($err_message , 'Email is already used by someone');
            }else{
                $_email = $email;
            }
        }else{
            array_push($err_message , 'Please use a valid email');
        }
    }else{
        array_push($err_message , 'Email can not be empty');
    }
    //validating username input
    if(!empty($username)){
        if(strlen($username) > 10){
            array_push($err_message , 'The maximum length you can use is 10');
        }else{
            $username_query = mysqli_query($connect , "SELECT * FROM Byers WHERE UserName = '$username' ");
            $count_username = mysqli_num_rows($username_query);
            if($count_username > 0){
                array_push($err_message , 'User Name is already used by someone');
            }else{
                $_username = $username;
            }
        }
    }else{
        array_push($err_message , 'Username can not be empty');
    }
    //validating phone number
    if(!empty($phone)){
        $number = ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $phone);
        $numberLen = strlen($number);
        if ($numberLen == 10 || $numberLen == 12){
            $phone_query = mysqli_query($connect , "SELECT * FROM Buyers WHERE PhoneNo = '$phone' ");
            $count_phone = mysqli_num_rows($phone_query);
            if($count_phone > 0){
                array_push($err_message , 'Phone number is already used');
             }else{
                 $_phone = $phone;
             }
        }else{
            array_push($err_message , 'The phone number is not valid');
        } 
    }else{
        array_push($err_message , 'Phone Number can not be empty');
    }
    //validating city input
    if(!empty($city)){
        $city_chk = strip_tags($city);
        if(strlen($city_chk) > 25){
            array_push($err_message , 'The maximum length you can use is 25');
        }elseif(preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/',$city_chk) && preg_match('/[0-9]/',$city_chk)){
            array_push($err_message , 'Only letter are allowed');
        }else{
            $_city = $city_chk;
        }
    }else{
            array_push($err_message , 'City can not be empty');
    }
    //validating address input
    if(!empty($address)){
        $address_chk = strip_tags($address);
        if(strlen($address_chk) > 100){
            array_push($err_message , 'The maximum length you can use is 100');
        }else{
            $_address = $address_chk;
        }
    }else{
        array_push($err_message , 'Full Address can not be empty');
    }
    //validating bank name input
    if(!empty($bank)){
        $bank_chk = strip_tags($bank);
        if(strlen($bank_chk) > 50){
            array_push($err_message , 'The maximum length you can use is 25');
        }elseif(preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/',$bank_chk) && preg_match('/[0-9]/',$bank_chk)){
            array_push($err_message , 'Only letter are allowed');
        }else{
            $_bank = $bank_chk;
        }
    }else{
            array_push($err_message , 'Bank Name can not be empty');
    }
    //validating bank account
    if(!empty($account)){
        $account = ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $account);
        $accountLen = strlen($account); 
        if ($accountLen < 30  or $accountLen > 5) {
            $_account = $account;
        }else{
            array_push($err_message , 'Your bank account is Invalid');
        }
    }else{
        array_push($err_message , 'Bank Account can not be empty');
    }
    //validating password
    if(!empty($password) && !empty($confirmPass)){
        if($password === $confirmPass){
            if(strlen($password) < 6 && strlen($password) > 25){
                array_push($err_message , 'Your password must be between 6 and 25 characthers only');
            }else{
                if(preg_match('/[a-z]/', $password) && preg_match('/[A-Z]/', $_POST['password']) && preg_match('/\d/', $password) && preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z\d]/', $password)){
                    $_password = $password;
                    $enc_pass = password_hash($_password , PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                }else{
                    array_push($err_message , 'use : at least 1 - capital letter , 1-special charachter and 1-number');
                }
            }
        }else{
            array_push($err_message , 'Please confirm password again');
        }
    }else{
        array_push($err_message , 'Password can not be empty');
    }

    if(count($err_message)){
        $first_query= mysqli_query($connect , "INSERT INTO Buyers values('','$_firstname','_$lastname','_$email','$_username',
        '$_phone','$_city','$_address','$_bank','$_account','$enc_pass')");

        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['success'] = "Registred Sccessfully";
        header('location: login.php');
    }


}
```

?>

Comment: Long story short, if it's code you wrote -and- you can't understand it, it's never safe enough. Please try to narrow down the problem with more specific notes regarding specific lines of code, so you evidence an effort to aleviate your pair programmers task.

Comment: yeah you are right, and i am just beginner so i will work more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end of your function, you're simply not checking `$err_message` correctly. If `count($err_message)` is true, you should be handling your error, not inserting the data into the database.

```
if(!count($err_message)) {
    $first_query= mysqli_query($connect , "INSERT INTO Buyers values('','$_firstname','_$lastname','_$email','$_username',
    '$_phone','$_city','$_address','$_bank','$_account','$enc_pass')");

    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['success'] = "Registred Sccessfully";
    header('location: login.php');
    exit;
}

// Display form again, and display the `$err_message`s.
```

As far as security goes, ditch `mysqli_real_escape_string()` all together. Binding variables is the most trusted, and safest way to go. My recommendation: Take a look into PDO. It's by far the easiest way to do this.